# Is Django's Session model usable with memcached sessions?

Tags: django

Recently we switched to memcached sessions from django's default DB sessions.

We've been using the contrib session model to remove session based on a session_key: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/models.py

```
Session.objects.get(session_key=key).delete()
```

Once we switched to memcached sessions the above query raises a DoesNotExist exception.

Is Django's Session model usable with memcached sessions? If so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides a [`django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs#using-cached-sessions) session backend which is supposed to achieve what you need so long as the cache is configured properly.

As suggested by yourself, the `Session` model is used by the `db` backend. To use the `cache` backend, you could do the following (so you keep using the API and make the code future proof).

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache import SessionStore
session = SessionStore(session_key)
session.delete()
```

That's how it's done in the [Sessions middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py).
*This method should work whatever the backend, which is likely a prefered behavior should you decide to move to another backend in the future.*

Comment: We're using sessions.backends.cache. It just seems the Session model is for DB sessions only.

Comment: @BrianCray That sounds right from looking at [the source code for `contrib.sessions`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py). You might want to have a look there for the `SessionStore.delete` method!

Comment: @BrianCray I updated my answer to reflect you suggestions, and offer an answer that only uses the API provided by the `sessions` module.

Answer (score 1):

```
mc = memcache.Client(settings.CACHE_BACKEND[:-1].split('//')[1].split(';'))
mc.delete(str(key))
```

Comment: That's what solved it. The contrib session model doesn't seem to work with cache sessions, only db sessions.